# COG not rendering in web maps

Tags: cloud-optimized-geotiff

I have started working with COG and STAC again. I generated COG using [GDAL](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/cog.html). I stored it in Google Cloud Storage (GCS) and a sample is accessible [HERE](https://storage.googleapis.com/philsa-cloud-optimized-geotiff/DIWATA2/SMI_L1C_COG/D2_SMI_2018-11-15T051831_2018-11-15T235959_L1C_COG.tif). I cannot render the image in web maps such as to http://tiles.rdnt.io/. I am also adding the COG as an asset to a [STAC Item](https://stacspec.org/en) and load it to a STAC Browser. The webmap (leaflet) from STAC Browser can also not load the COG image.

The sample is accessible to the public. It has a uniform permission policy in GCS. It is downloadable. I want to know what could be wrong with my COG image and what could be the solutions for it.

**Added later...**

In tiles.rdnt.io here are the errors shown in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 530 ()

GET https://a-catcher.maptiks.com/store/a.gif?cat=map&act=mapactivity&lbl=pan&intr=true&bbox=119.26758%2C5.16207%2C124.94751%2C8.7928&cp=122.10754%2C6.98095&zm=8&mid=tiles.rdnt.io&lib=leaflet&msid=d59e01b9-b149-4a5d-f405-1a07bdd16fea&tid=a32dd5ef-81d8-4a74-91f2-b26973e7574e&t=1689127239332.6301&expires_at=1689732039.3326302 530
```

While in STAC Browser, the error is:

```
HEAD https://storage.googleapis.com/philsa-cloud-optimized-geotiff/DIWATA2/SMI_L1C_COG/D2_SMI_2018-11-15T051831_2018-11-15T235959_L1C_COG.tif.ovr 404

georaster-layer-for-leaflet.js:755 TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at it.blockSize (georaster.browser.bundle.min.js:8:126658)
    at it.requestData (georaster.browser.bundle.min.js:8:126342)
    at it.fetch (georaster.browser.bundle.min.js:8:125506)
    at async W.getTileOrStrip (georaster.browser.bundle.min.js:8:115794)
```

**Added later...**

I initially used gdal Python API bindings.

```
translate_options = gdal.TranslateOptions(format='COG')
translated_ds = gdal.Translate(destName=ds_filepath, srcDS=src_ds, options=translate_options)
```

Then, later on, I used the [rio-cogeo version](https://cogeotiff.github.io/rio-cogeo/API/). But still have the same effect. I replaced profile `webp` as `deflate`.

**PS**

[HERE](https://storage.googleapis.com/philsa-cloud-optimized-geotiff/DIWATA2/SMI_STACK/D2_SMI_2018-11-15T051831_2018-11-15T235959_stack.tif) is a copy of the regular TIFF just in case someone wants to inspect it.